# Mapreduce Job -Taking too long to complete

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

We have written a mapreduce job to process log files. As of now we have around 52GB of input files but it is taking around an hour to process the data.It creates only one reducer job by default.Often we get to see a timeout error in the reduce task and then it restarts and gets completed. Below is the stats for the successful completion of the job. Kindly let us know how the performance can be improved.

```
File System Counters
            FILE: Number of bytes read=876100387
            FILE: Number of bytes written=1767603407
            FILE: Number of read operations=0
            FILE: Number of large read operations=0
            FILE: Number of write operations=0
            HDFS: Number of bytes read=52222279591
            HDFS: Number of bytes written=707429882
            HDFS: Number of read operations=351
            HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
            HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
            Failed reduce tasks=1
            Launched map tasks=116
            Launched reduce tasks=2
            Other local map tasks=116
            Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=9118125
            Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=7083783
            Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3039375
            Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=2361261
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=3039375
            Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=2361261
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=25676640000
            Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=20552415744
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=49452982
            Map output records=5730971
            Map output bytes=864140911
            Map output materialized bytes=876101077
            Input split bytes=13922
            Combine input records=0
            Combine output records=0
            Reduce input groups=1082133
            Reduce shuffle bytes=876101077
            Reduce input records=5730971
            Reduce output records=5730971
            Spilled Records=11461942
            Shuffled Maps =116
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=116
            GC time elapsed (ms)=190633
            CPU time spent (ms)=4536110
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=340458307584
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=1082745069568
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=378565820416
    Shuffle Errors
            BAD_ID=0
            CONNECTION=0
            IO_ERROR=0
            WRONG_LENGTH=0
            WRONG_MAP=0
            WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
            Bytes Read=52222265669
    File Output Format Counters 
            Bytes Written=707429882
```

I am getting a classcast exception as below if I increase the number of reducers. I guess the issue comes from the partitioner class.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.CompositeWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.CompositeWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.ActualKeyPartitioner.getPartition(ActualKeyPartitioner.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.ExchgLogsMapper.map(ExchgLogsMapper.java:56)
    at com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.ExchgLogsMapper.map(ExchgLogsMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
```

## My Partitioner class

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.HashPartitioner;

public class ActualKeyPartitioner extends Partitioner<CompositeKey, Text> {

    HashPartitioner<Text, Text> hashPartitioner = new HashPartitioner<Text, Text>();
    Text newKey = new Text();

    @Override
    public int getPartition(CompositeKey key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {

        try {
            // Execute the default partitioner over the first part of the key
            newKey.set(key.getSubject());
            return hashPartitioner.getPartition(newKey, value, numReduceTasks);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return (int) (Math.random() * numReduceTasks); // this would return
                                                            // a random value in
                                                            // the range
            // [0,numReduceTasks)
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapper Code**

```
public class ExchgLogsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, List<Text>, CompositeKey, Writable> {
    String recepientAddresses = "";
    public static final String DELIVER = "DELIVER";
    public static final String RESOLVED = "Resolved";
    public static final String JUNK = "Junk E-mail";
    public static final String SEMICOLON = ";";
    public static final String FW1 = "FW: ";
    public static final String FW2 = "Fw: ";
    public static final String FW3 = "FWD: ";
    public static final String FW4 = "Fwd: ";
    public static final String FW5 = "fwd: ";
    public static final String RE1 = "RE: ";
    public static final String RE2 = "Re: ";
    public static final String RE3 = "re: ";


    Text mailType = new Text("NEW");
    Text fwType = new Text("FW");
    Text reType = new Text("RE");
    Text recepientAddr = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, List<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String subj = null;
        int lstSize=values.size() ;
        if ((lstSize >= 26)) {
            if (values.get(8).toString().equals(DELIVER)) {
                if (!(ExclusionList.exclusions.contains(values.get(18).toString()))) {
                    if (!(JUNK.equals((values.get(12).toString())))) {
                        subj = values.get(17).toString();
                        recepientAddresses = values.get(11).toString();
                        String[] recepientAddressArr = recepientAddresses.split(SEMICOLON);
                        if (subj.startsWith(FW1) || subj.startsWith(FW2) || subj.startsWith(FW3)
                                || subj.startsWith(FW4) || subj.startsWith(FW5)) {
                            mailType = fwType;
                            subj = subj.substring(4);
                        } else if (subj.startsWith(RE1) || subj.startsWith(RE2) || subj.startsWith(RE3)) {
                            mailType = reType;
                            subj = subj.substring(4);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < recepientAddressArr.length; i++) {
                            CompositeKey ckey = new CompositeKey(subj, values.get(0).toString());
                            recepientAddr.set(recepientAddressArr[i]);
                            CompositeWritable out = new CompositeWritable(mailType, recepientAddr, values.get(18),
                                    values.get(0));
                            context.write(ckey, out);
//                          System.err.println(out);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's stopping you in increasing the number of reducers ?

Comment: I am getting a classcast exception as  if I increase the number of reducers. I guess the issue comes from the partitioner class. I have edited the question with more details

Comment: is key.getSubject a Text? 

can you try 

return (key.getSubject.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks; 

rather than creating a hash partitioner instance. This is the code from the HashPartitioner implementation.

Comment: What is at line 56 of ExchgLogsMapper com.emaar.bigdata.exchg.logs.ExchgLogsMapper.map(ExchgLogsMapper.java:56)

Comment: @ Arun... Line 56 is writing the output to the context.        context.write(ckey, out);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few sysouts in the reducer code inside the loop which was writing lots of logs and after removing them the reducer gets finished in couple of minutes.!