# Mapreduce -Timeout while reducer reaches 67%

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

We are getting a timeout exception when the reducer reaches 67% which I believe is after the sort phase and before reduce phase. Please advise which parameters we should be looking to resolve the issue.

```
16/06/15 16:58:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/06/15 16:58:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 24%
16/06/15 16:59:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 28%
16/06/15 16:59:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 30%
16/06/15 16:59:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 33%
16/06/15 17:00:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 52%
16/06/15 17:00:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
16/06/15 17:05:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1465992294703_0001_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
```

**Driver Class**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CSVLineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CSVNLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class ExchgLogsTransposeDriver extends Configured implements Tool {


    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        String outPath=null;
        String inPath=null;

        if(args==null ||args.length==0){
             inPath="C:\\HadoopWS\\infile\\";
             outPath="C:\\HadoopWS\\outfile\\";

        }else{
            inPath=args[0];
            outPath=args[1];


        }


        Path output =new Path(outPath);
        Path input =new Path(inPath);

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if (hdfs.exists(output)) {
            hdfs.delete(output, true);
        }
        conf.set(CSVLineRecordReader.FORMAT_DELIMITER, "\"");
        conf.set(CSVLineRecordReader.FORMAT_SEPARATOR, ",");
        conf.setInt(CSVNLineInputFormat.LINES_PER_MAP, 500000);
        conf.setBoolean(CSVLineRecordReader.IS_ZIPFILE, false);
        Job job = new Job(conf);

        job.setJarByClass(ExchgLogsTransposeDriver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ExchgLogsMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(CompositeKey.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(CompositeWritable.class);
//        job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        job.setMapSpeculativeExecution(true);

        job.setPartitionerClass(ActualKeyPartitioner.class);
        job.setGroupingComparatorClass(ActualKeyGroupingComparator.class);
        job.setSortComparatorClass(CompositeKeyComparator.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ExchgLogsReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(CompositeWritable.class);

        job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", input.getName());
        job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true");
//        job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec");


        job.setInputFormatClass(CSVNLineInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inPath));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outPath));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new ExchgLogsTransposeDriver(), args));
    }
}
```

**Reducer Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class ExchgLogsReducer extends Reducer<CompositeKey, CompositeWritable, NullWritable, Text> {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ExchgLogsReducer.class);
    public static final String NEW = "NEW";
    public static final String FW = "FW";
    public static final String RE = "RE";
    public static final int ZERO = 0;
    Text res = new Text();

    @Override
    public void reduce(CompositeKey key, Iterable<CompositeWritable> value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<CompositeValueObj> cache = new ArrayList<CompositeValueObj>();

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<CompositeWritable> it = value.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            CompositeWritable currWritable = new CompositeWritable();
            currWritable = it.next();
            CompositeValueObj obj = new CompositeValueObj();
            obj.setRecepient((currWritable.getRecepient().toString()));
            obj.setSender(currWritable.getSender().toString());
            obj.setType(currWritable.getType().toString());
            obj.setTimestamp(currWritable.getTimestamp().toString());
            cache.add(obj);
            // System.out.println(new Text(" "+"\t" + obj.getRecepient() + "\t"
            // + obj.getSender() + "\t" +obj.getType()+ "\t" +
            // obj.getTimestamp()));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < cache.size(); i++) {
            CompositeValueObj currobj = cache.get(i);
            String receiver = currobj.getRecepient().toString();
            String origSender = currobj.getSender().toString();

            String dateFrom = currobj.getTimestamp().toString();
            System.out.println(key.getSubject() + "  " + "i==>" + i + cache.size());
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cache.size(); j++) {
                response = new StringBuilder(key.getSubject()).append(",").append(receiver).append(",");
                CompositeValueObj nextObj = cache.get(j);
                System.out.println(key.getSubject() + "  " + "j==>" + j);

                String dateTo = nextObj.getTimestamp().toString();
                String newSender = nextObj.getSender().toString();
                String newRecepient = nextObj.getRecepient().toString();
                String mailType = nextObj.getType().toString();

                // System.out.println(mailType+ "==>"+receiver+
                // "==>"+newRecepient);

                if (receiver.equals(newRecepient)) {
                    response.append(origSender).append(",");
                    response.append("N,0,0,").append(dateFrom);
                    break;
                }

                if (receiver.equals(newSender) && ((mailType.equals(RE) || (mailType.equals(FW))))) {
                    if (mailType.equals(RE)) {
                        response.append(origSender).append(",");
                        response.append("Y,");
                        response.append(getTimeDiff(dateFrom, dateTo));
                        response.append(",0,").append(dateTo);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (mailType.equals(FW)) {
                        response.append(origSender).append(",");
                        response.append("Y,0,");
                        response.append(getTimeDiff(dateFrom, dateTo));
                        response.append(",").append(dateTo);
                        break;
                    }

                } else {
                    response.append(origSender).append(",");
                    response.append("N,0,0,").append(dateFrom);
                }

            }
            if (i + 1 == cache.size()) {
                response = new StringBuilder(key.getSubject()).append(",").append(receiver).append(",");
                response.append(origSender).append(",");
                response.append("N,0,0,").append(dateFrom);

            }
            res.set(response.toString());
            // System.err.println(key.getSubject()+new
            // Text(response.toString()));
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), res);
        }

    }

    private static double getTimeDiff(String date1, String date2) {
        double diff = 0;
        double weekend = 0;
        boolean isWEchain=false;
        boolean isWESent=false;

        if (date1 == null || date2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try {
            Date from = sdf.parse(date1);
            Date to = sdf.parse(date2);
            Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal1.setTime(from);
            cal2.setTime(to);
            int noOfDaysWE = 0;
            System.out.println(cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            System.out.println(cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            if ((((Calendar.FRIDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                    || (Calendar.SATURDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)))
                    && ((Calendar.FRIDAY == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                            || (Calendar.SATURDAY == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))))
                    ) {

                isWEchain =true;
            }else if((((Calendar.FRIDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                    || (Calendar.SATURDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)))
                    && (((Calendar.FRIDAY != cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                            && (Calendar.SATURDAY != cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)))))){
                isWESent=true;
                if(Calendar.FRIDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
                    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                }
                cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR,20);
                cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
                cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
            }
            System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
            System.out.println(cal2.getTime());
            System.out.println(isWESent);
            diff=cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis();
            if(diff < 0 ){
            return 0;   
            }

            while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
                if ((Calendar.FRIDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
                        || (Calendar.SATURDAY == cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))) {
                    noOfDaysWE++;
                }
                cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }




            if (noOfDaysWE != 0) {
                weekend = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(noOfDaysWE);
            }
            if(isWEchain && (noOfDaysWE <= 2)){
                return 0;

            }

            System.out.println(diff);
            diff = diff - weekend;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (diff != 0)
            return diff / 1000;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        System.out.println(getTimeDiff("2016-06-03T19:41:48.781Z", "2016-06-05T07:21:01.000Z"));
    }

}
```

Comment: how many reducers have you set?

Comment: Till now what have you tried. Also put some code snippet. Looks like there some issues in the reducer code only.

Comment: @cyberPheonix  Only one reducer gets created by default.

Comment: @ishan Have included my code as well..

Comment: May not be related, but the reducer key value class set in the driver does not match the prototype in your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few sysouts in the reducer code inside the loop which was writing lots of logs and after removing them the reducer gets finished in couple of minutes.!

Comment: Not sure on that. I wrote a simple hive query to copy 50 thousand rows from a table into new table in different DB. While the map was quick to reach 100%, reduce went slow till 33%  then immediately reached 67% and been struck here since 1 hour now.

Answer (score 1):

From 67%-100% the actual reduce code gets executed, so none of your reduce tasks are getting completed. There may be too much data going to the reducer or may be there is an infinite loop on some sort.

Comment: When I run with comparatively small file which is of size 3 GB the reducer gets completed successfully. So there may not be infinite loop. So increasing the reducer count might help. But I am facing some exception if I increase the reducer count as discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773114/mapreduce-job-taking-too-long-to-complete

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in to `mapred.task.timeout` is is milliseconds in `mapred-site.xml`.

after changing the property, you have to restart all the tranckers.(job + task)

Tip : If you want print all the configuration at run time to check whether applied or not use this below code snippet from driver.
for ex:

```
final JobConf conf = new JobConf(config, this.getClass());

try {
            conf.writeXml(System.out);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: ..Thanks for your inputs. I have seen this parameter which is 300000 in our case. As per the documentation it is "The number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string." So I doubt if there is any issue with the cluster or with my code and it requires a fix or my timeout is not a optimal value whch needs to be changed.

Comment: Tried increasing the time to 600000 and it timesout again after 600 seconds.

Comment: can you give the code snippet of what your reducer is doing? Have you printed all the config as said above ? if so are you able to get the changed value for that?

Comment: I havent printed the values. But the new value has taken effect since i see the error as  AttemptID:attempt_1465997799084_0001_r_000000_0 Timed out after 600 secs. Have edited the question with my code as well.

Comment: 1) put Logs which prints time  of before  start after finish  2) in the above code you can comment block one after another to find out the issue(you can understand when timeout is happening and when its not)?

Comment: The job gets completed when I run with a file of around 3 GB. But the actual files we want to process is around 40 GB where it is getting failed. Can increasing the number of reducers help here ?

Comment: can try that since data volume is high

Comment: Tried that.. But facing some exception which I am discussing here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773114/mapreduce-job-taking-too-long-to-complete. Please bare with me since it's my first mapreduce job.. Appreciate all your help.,

Comment: Thanks for the concern.. I increased the reducers to 3 but still it fails. I commented the method getTimeDiff which you can see in my reducer which takes time it still throws same timeout error.

Comment: can you added log level to debug? like this for mapper and reducer respectively..  conf.set("mapreduce.map.log.level", LogLevel.DEBUG.name());
  conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.log.level", LOGLevel.DEBUG.name());